# command not found in shell file when sub-command is added

Tags: linux, docker, dbt

I'm running an .sh file in a docker container running debian and when I pass an argument (dbt) it works as expected (I get a list of sub-commands to use) but when I add any sub-command (dbt run) I get an error command not found.

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAM_RUN_SCRIPT="$1"

echo " ------------ RUN_PIPELINE.SH ------------------------- "

echo " Performing run : $PARAM_RUN_SCRIPT ..."

"$PARAM_RUN_SCRIPT"

echo " ------------ RUN_PIPELINE.SH ------------------------- "
echo " Finished!!! "
```

Comment: If you want to pass an argument _list_ -- lists should be stored as arrays, not strings. That is, instead of `yourscript "dbt run"`, you should use `yourscript dbt run`, store `param_run_script=( "$@" )` and then invoke with `"${param_run_script[@]}"`

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: *I'm trying to store a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: (As a completely separate note -- don't use `.sh` extensions for bash scripts; [executables shouldn't have extensions _at all_](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), and as bash and sh aren't mutually compatible, using `.sh` for a bash script adds additional confusion -- making people think they can use `sh yourscript` instead of `bash yourscript`, when the former will fail as soon as you use any bash-only syntax).